# EXPECT_THROW - Actual: it throws a different type, google tests

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix, googletest, throw

Hi guys so i have this constructor

```
Matrix::Matrix(size_t row, size_t col)
{
  if(row < 1 || col < 1)
    throw new std::runtime_error("Minimalni velikost matice je 1x1");
  matrix = std::vector<std::vector< double > >(row,std::vector<double>(col, 0));
}
```

and this test

```
Matrix *TestedMatrix;
EXPECT_THROW(TestedMatrix = new Matrix(-2,3),std::runtime_error );
```

but im still getting that exepction is of different type. I also tried `std::runtime_error*` but result is the same. I wanted use EXPECT_ANY_THROW at first but it was not displayed in my code coverage. Thanks for help ! :)

Comment: `size_t(-2)` is not less than 1!  size_t is unsigned type - read about https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvojkov%C3%BD_dopln%C4%9Bk

Comment: as far as I can guess here - what you really get is `std::bad_alloc`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't call `new`.

```
Matrix::Matrix(size_t row, size_t col)
{
  if(row < 1 || col < 1)
    throw std::runtime_error("Minimalni velikost matice je 1x1");
  matrix = std::vector<std::vector< double > >(row,std::vector<double>(col, 0));
}
```

`new` is going to return a `void*` which is why you are getting the "exception is of different type" error.

Comment: Yea thank you for your response. The problem is I cant change the code. Im just doing tests so do you have any idea how to solve this with calling               new ?

Comment: Can you try `EXPECT_THROW(TestedMatrix = new Matrix(-2,3),void*);`?

Comment: No, its not working. Alsa can I ask you if its better to use Matrix *TestedMatrix or Matrix Tested Matrix. Whats better about testing with pointer or vise versa . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `size_t` is an alias for `std::size_t`, you're seeing signed-to-unsigned conversion here (and your compiler should be warning you about that; check that you've enabled sufficient warnings in your build).

`-2` gets converted to a very large positive value (very nearly `SIZE_MAX`), so the likelihood is that the constructor is throwing `std::bad_alloc`.

You need to pass `0` to the constructor to exercise the code path that throws `std::runtime_error*`.  (And you can simplify the check to `if (!row || !col)`, since 0 is the only unsigned value less than 1).

```
EXPECT_THROW(Matrix(0,3), std::runtime_error*);
EXPECT_THROW(Matrix(3,0), std::runtime_error*);
```

As an aside, I recommend that you throw *by value* rather than using `new`.